# How to launch an activity with a specific tab?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-tabs

I've gone through many examples, questions and tutorials but I've never seen an activity launch (launch a new intent) with a specific tab. I know that one can use `.setCurrentTab` to switch to a tab, but this can be done only from inside the parent activity tab. How about launching a specific tab contained in one activity from a different activity? Is it possible? If so, then how?

In my code, on a standard activity launch user is shown the first tab, but I want him to go to the fourth tab in case he is being redirected from another activity.
My TabHost code (MyTabActivity):

```
int tabIndex = 0;

          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("top10").setIndicator("Top 10").setContent(R.id.Top_10));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("billable").setIndicator("Billable").setContent(R.id.Billable));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("product").setIndicator("Product").setContent(R.id.Product));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("regular").setIndicator("Regular").setContent(R.id.General));


          mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabIndex);
```

Now in another activity:

```
public void gotoTab() {
//This will take me to the first tab
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyTabActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
//How to I make it take me to the fourth tab?
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to handle it yourself with `setCurrentTab` in the new activity's constructor.

While calling, you should put additional values in the intent -

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyTabActivity.class);
i.putExtra("FirstTab", 4);
```

And in constructor of MyTabActivity -

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int tabToOpen = i.getIntExtra("FirstTab", -1);
if (tabToOpen!=-1) {
    // Open the right tab
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with your tab position

Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, TabScreenActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(ConstantString.ViewTab,1);
        startActivity(intent);

And in constructor of TabScreenActivity

if (getIntent() != null) {

```
        tabPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra(ConstantString.ViewTab, tabPosition);

        if (tabPosition == 1) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }


    } else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }
```