# open activity on specific tab selected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to implement `Tablayout` `addOnTabSelectedListener` to open a new Activity on a certain tab click. There are 3 tabs and at present they are connected with fragments. I want to start an activity when I click position 1 tab. I can do that in `onTabSelected` but before opening activity it shows the fragment attached to that same position. How to remove that fragment?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabs;
    private ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewpager);


        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab());
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab());
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab());

        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);

        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewpager));

    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager viewPager) {

        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag3(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
        onTabSelectedListener(viewPager);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}


    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager viewPager) {

        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag3(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
        onTabSelectedListener(viewPager);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch an activity with a specific tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124372/how-to-launch-an-activity-with-a-specific-tab)

Comment: You're asking "Can I do it with ...?". Just try it. Launch Intent from onTabSelected and see.

Comment: Simply use _int position = tab.getPosition();_

Comment: I added the code to open activity as per position. Only problem is it shows `Frag2` first and then open Activity. How to remove the `Frag2` from adapter?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead the reason for this is that the `FragmentPagerAdapter` will keep all the views that it loads into memory forever. Where the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` disposes of views that fall outside the current

Also Override the adapter method `getItemPosition`

For example:

```
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //... your existing code

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396321/remove-fragment-page-from-viewpager-in-android)

it will recreate your fragment each time instead of loading them from memory first..

To start activity do it in your particular fragment's `onCreate()`

Hope this helps..

Comment: Its not working. Its opens activity but when I press back button, its shows the fragment page @rafsanahmad007

Comment: overwrite `onBackpressed` in your tabbed activity to open your `MainActivity` or other activity

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement, what i did is overlap textview on center of TabLayout using RelativeLayout & apply click event on textview. I can not post my layout please refer demo image

[image]